# Altair Color Scatter Plot on Condition

Tags: python, scatter-plot, altair, vega-lite

I have this df:

```
    x           y           term        s
0   0.000000    0.132653    matlab      0.893072
1   0.000000    0.142857    matrix      0.905120
2   0.012346    0.153061    laboratory  0.902610
3   0.987654    0.989796    be          0.857932
4   0.938272    0.959184    a           0.861948
```

The variable `s` tells us the "distance" of the term from the central line (slope 1).
And I need to make a scatterplot that looks like this:

[image: chart]

I have this code so far:

```
chart = alt.Chart(scatterdata_df).mark_circle().encode(
        x = alt.X('x:Q', axis = alt.Axis(tickMinStep = 0.05)),
        y = alt.Y('y:Q', axis = alt.Axis(tickMinStep = 0.05)),
        color=alt.condition('s:Q', alt.value('red'), alt.value('blue')),
        tooltip = ['term']
    ).properties(
        width = 500,
        height = 500
    ) 
chart
```

And that gives me an error.

```
Javascript Error: Expression parse error: (s:Q)?"red":"blue"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
```

When I just do `color = 's'` I get this, which is closer:
[image: chart2]

But again I need that double-gradient of colors. I know that the gradient is respective of the `s` variable, but I'm not sure how to make it have two gradients, one for each side of the central line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s:Q` is not a valid conditional statement. But, for example, you could write a condition like this:

```python
  color = alt.condition(alt.datum.s < 0, alt.value('red'), alt.value('blue'))
```

and points with `s < 0` would be colored red, and all others would be colored blue.

Alternatively, if you want to encode a continuous color scale by the value of `s` (rather than deciding between two colors based on a condition), you could do

```python
  color = 's:Q'
```

If you'd like to use a color scheme in this case that's different from the default, you can specify it this way:

```python
  color = alt.Color('s:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='redblue'))
```

where the string passed to the `scheme` argument is one of the built-in named color schemes, listed at https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#reference

For more information on customizing colors in Altair, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#customizing-colors

Comment: Thank you, Jake! Using the alt.Scale() with the `scheme` did the trick.

Comment: I did have one more question regarding my tickMinStep. If you see in my code I set it to 0.05 but the graph is still outputting ticks every 0.1, so I'm wondering how I should approach that.

Comment: If you have a new question, I'd suggest creating a new post.